# What is the criteria and/or process for an outlet (e.g. journal or conference) to get indexed by Microsoft Academic Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-cognitive-services, academic-graph

Other bibliometric databases have criteria and processes (sometimes unclear) for getting indexed by them. But I can't find that information for MAG. Does anyone have information on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "feedback" form on [Microsoft Academic](https://academic.microsoft.com) to suggest journals/conferences.

Comment: This is useful, thanks. But the question still remains, what's the selection process for stuff that's *currently* indexed?